# In Ogre, how to change FSAA level after createManual()?

Tags: ogre, render-to-texture

When I use a RTT (Render to Texture) in Ogre3D, I find that I need to change the FSAA level in rendering, because high FSAA levels give nice results, but cost performance, so I want to change its level:

```cpp
Ogre::TexturePtr tp = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleTonPtr()->createManual(name,...,fsaalevel,"");
tp->getBuffer()->getRenderTarget()->addcamera..addviewport ..etc(startup);
```

Using this line afterwards is not useful, because the second line below is the original value:

```cpp
tp->setFSAA(0,"")
tp->getBuffer()->getRenderTarget()->getFSAA();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs on Ogre::Texture::setFSAA](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Texture.html#ab930e26d3531e20604e22e3324759ad4):

> This option will be ignored if TU_RENDERTARGET is not part of the usage options on this texture, or if the hardware does not support it.

You are probably missing the `TU_RENDERTARGET`. Check the [Ogre Wiki on Render to Texture](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Intermediate+Tutorial+7) for a step by step guide.

Comment: Thank you very much! TU_RENDERTARGET is have,and hardware is supported and you can try it,it doesn't work. It's not a newer question.

Comment: I don't understand your comments.

Comment: You think I use createManual without TU_RENDERTARGET. But I use! My hardware supports it because I can see effect by set different fsaa level. I just want to change fass level after createManual but I change textruePtr's fass level but RenderTarget's fsaa is not change and render to texture(rtt) use RenderTarget's fsaa to render. Then I have no way to solve it.I'am Chinese, and my English isn't good. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, please be more clear on what you already tried in the future. Your code suggests you didn't use TU_RENDERTARGET.

Comment: Can you help me？ I have no way.

Comment: No. I usually ask question here. OK,I will ask on it.